# Integrating Facebook "Like" button with callback - not displaying in activity

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to integrate the Facebook 'Like' button, where the 'Like' action is integrated with a callback function.  It seems to be working, except the 'Like' activity isn't showing up on Facebook.

I am testing this with my own Facebook account and don't see the activity in my feed, profile page, or Activity Log.

Here is my URL:
http://flevy.com/powerpoint-plugin-test

Here is my code:

```
    <script src=\"http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        // init the FB JS SDK
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'xxxxxx', // App ID from the App Dashboard
          status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
          cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
        });
        FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
      };
    </script>


    <div class=\"fb-like\" data-href=\"$share_url\" data-send=\"false\" data-layout=\"box_count\" data-width=\"50\" data-show-faces=\"false\"></div>


    // facebook callback
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
        deliverEmail();
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

I would first fix the errors on the Open Graph debugger:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fflevy.com%2Fpowerpoint-plugin-test

**Errors that must be fixed**

```
Object Invalid Value
Object at URL 'http://flevy.com/powerpoint-plugin-test' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value '//flevy.com/images/slides.gif' for property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.
```

Answer (score 2):

Your javascript is throwing an error saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'setAutoResize'

AFAIK, the setAutoResize function is deprecated now. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/#september-2012

And, as far as I understand either ways, even the [function that replaced this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/), is supposed to be used when you are loading this inside the Facebook Canvas.

So, please check what you are doing here! :)

Answer (score 0):

This page has a lot of HTML syntax inconsistencies / validation problems.  You switch from single quotes, double quotes and no quotes in your HTML for your attribute values.  The code is also missing some terminating tags.  This can cause some erratic behavior. Your JavaScript has the same problems where you use single and then double in the same script block... while that does look valid.

**You can run validation here:**

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fflevy.com%2Fpowerpoint-plugin-test&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

The Open Graph validation that @DrBeza is talking about should also be resolved.  Not sure why the framework doesn't like the non-protocol specific URL, but just add http:// or https:// to that image.

After the cleanup this should be easier to troubleshoot or the problem may be a result of needed cleanup.